# How to avoid Spring Boot uses my MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter Bean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot 2. I'd like to define a singleton bean of type **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter**, which will be used only by other beans.

By default, Spring Boot picks up a user defined MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and replaces the default instance with the one provided by the user, as stated by official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper):

> If you provide any @Beans of type MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, they replace the default value in the MVC configuration. Also, a convenience bean of type HttpMessageConverters is provided (and is always available if you use the default MVC configuration). It has some useful methods to access the default and user-enhanced message converters.

This is my configuration class:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter myJacksonConverter() {
...
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public MyClient myClient(){
     MyClient c = new MyClient();
     c.setConverter(myJacksonConverter());
     return c;
}
```

So, I want MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter as a singleton bean, but I **don't want** that Spring Boot uses it at global application level.

Comment: Why does your bean have to be a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`? Can't it just be a custom subclass of `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider not defining your custom converter as a `@Bean`. Instead, you could create your custom converter and store it in a field of a `@Configuration` class and then reference it from there. The `@Configuration` class will only be created once so you're guaranteed to only get a single instance of your custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

If it is used only inside the same config class, you can avoid to use `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Bean
public MyClient myClient(){
     MyClient c = new MyClient();
     c.setConverter(myJacksonConverter());
     return c;
}

private static MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter myJacksonConverter() {

}
```

Comment: In the original example I provided, the scope of the MyClient bean is singleton, but in case of prototype scope (the real case I'm facing), the myJacksonConverter method would be called many times.

Comment: In that case, use can use `Singleton Design Pattern` in your Config class. And provide static reference for using the bean from outside of the class.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works .. Define a class that extends from MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and autowire it.

````
class MyCustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {} 

@Bean
public MyCustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter myJacksonConverter() {
...
}

@Bean
public MyClient myClient(){
     MyClient c = new MyClient();
     c.setConverter(myCustomJacksonConverter());
     return c;
}```
````

Comment: This won't work unfortunately. As `MyCustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` extends `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` it will replace the auto-configured default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.